# Selecting multiple features by ID-attribute from list using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, features, list, select-by-expression

With PyQGIS I would like to use several `"ID"`s (in a list) to select certain objects in order to make them available later in a temporary layer. I know how to select one or a few more objects, but my list can contain a large number of `"ID"`s. My attempt to run

```py
for x in list:
    layer.selectByExpression("id = '{}'".format(x))
```

in a `for` loop did not work. How can I select multiple features in a data set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this way (without `for` loop):

```
id_list = [1, 2, 5]
layer.selectByExpression("id in {}".format(tuple(id_list)))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can also:

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('mylayer')[0]
layer.removeSelection()
mylist = [0,2,4]
layer.select([f.id() for f in layer.getFeatures() if f['id'] in mylist])
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply do:

```py
id_list = [4, 5, 7, 11, 14]
layer.selectByIds(id_list)
```

And, for the sake of interest, I think that a slight variation of your original for loop would work fine if you pass an additional argument to specify the select behavior as `QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection` (the default is `QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection`). If you are working with feature ids, you would use the variable '$id' in your expression:

```py
id_list = [4, 5, 7, 11, 14]
for i in id_list:
    layer.selectByExpression("$id = {}".format(i), QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)
```

On the other hand, if you are matching integers in your list to an attribute field called "id", you could use the following expression:

```py
id_list = [4, 5, 7, 11, 14]
for i in id_list:
    layer.selectByExpression("\"id\" = {}".format(i), QgsVectorLayer.AddToSelection)
```

By the way, using the word 'list' as a variable name is not recommended and can cause unexpected behavior- 'list' is a built in class in Python. If you just run:

```py
print(list)
```

in the Python console, you get an output like:

```py
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: @MrXsquared, your comment was thought provoking to me and led me to improve my answer (I think)-  so thank you! Yes, the first solution refers to feature ids, but I have edited my answer to cover both cases for the second- since, after re-reading the OP's question, it is not clear to me which one they are actually using.